# Download SQL Server Backup Amazon

Tags: amazon-aws

Boa tarde, alguém saberia me dizer como eu faço para fazer donwload do meu backup da RDS da amazon? Entrando pelo Sql Server Manager Studio consigo aparece a opção e que o backup está no diretório D:\RDSDBDATA\BACKUP\ como faço para acessar ele?

Comment: E indo pelo próprio diretório não vai?

Comment: @VictorGomes eu não sei como acessar esse diretório. A instância de VM do servidor de aplicação não possui esse diretório e o banco de dados fica no RDS eu não sei, como acessar, pesquisei no google mais não descobri ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Direto do [FAQ do Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/faqs/):

> **P: Onde estão armazenados meus snapshots de banco dados e backups automatizados e como administro sua retenção?**
>
> Os backups automatizados e os snapshots de BD do Amazon RDS são
>   armazenados no S3.
>
> Você pode utilizar o AWS Management Console ou a API ModifyDBInstance
>   para gerenciar por quanto tempo seus backups automáticos serão
>   mantidos, modificando o parâmetro RetentionPeriod. Se você deseja
>   desativar completamente os backups automatizados, isso é possível ao
>   configurar o período de retenção para 0 (não recomendado). Você pode
>   gerenciar seus snapshots de banco de dados de usuário através da seção
>   de snapshots do AWS Management Console. Também é possível visualizar
>   uma lista de snapshots de banco de dados de usuário para uma Instância
>   de banco de dados específica utilizando a API DescribeDBSnapshots e
>   excluir snapshots com a API DeleteDBSnapshot.

Comment: e como faço pra fazer donwload dos backups?

Comment: Não faz. Você pode restaurar. Se quiser fazer o backup, vai ter que trafegar para um gerenciador seu, isto é, rodar uma rotina de backup através do Management Studio, o que não é indicado mas pode ser feito.

Comment: porque não é indicado? Se meu cliente quiser um backup preciso dele.

Comment: Considero não indicado porque você vai trafegar todo o seu banco de dados até o seu local de backup. A Amazon te cobra "Transfer Out" e se a frequência for alta, pode tornar a sua conta na Amazon cara.

Comment: Ok, e como faria esse backup saberia me dizer? Usando comando t-Sql ocorre problema de permissão.